# Electrostatic Induction Metal vs Insulator

Tags: electrostatics, electromagnetic-induction, dielectric

If we have a small dielectric sphere and a point charge, they will experience an attractive force due to electrostatic induction.

Likewise, if we have a small metallic sphere and a point charge, they will experience an attractive force due to electrostatic induction.

Can I accurately say that the attractive force for the metallic case is always greater than or essentially equal to the attractive force in the dielectric case?

I think this because the screening in conductor is perfect, so the induced charge distribution will be large enough to cancel the entire field from the charge, whereas in the dielectric, the screening can be much worse or (for high kappa materials) at best approximately as good.

Comment: I think they should be equal(for E < breakdown field) ofc, but it is just my analysis and I may be wrong can anyone confirm?